# Dirichlet theorem of the form a+nb

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Dirichlet theorem holds great fascination for me, prompting a particular question. I am aware that for coprime integers a and b, the arithmetic sequence defined by a, a+b, a+2b, a+3b, and so on, contains an infinite number of prime numbers.

Let us express this sequence as a+nb, where n represents a positive integer. Assuming we select 6 as the value for a, it is then possible to choose any prime number greater than or equal to 7 as the value for b, resulting in a pair of coprime numbers.

Now, consider an arbitrarily large prime number b. Can I ascertain that there will always exist a larger prime number n, such that the expression a+nb yields a prime number? Alternatively, can n be factored solely by prime numbers greater than b?

For instance, if we take a=6 and b=7, we observe that 83 is a prime number, and we find that n=11 satisfies the equation 6+7n=83. As 11 is greater than 7, this verifies our claim for the specific values a=6 and b=7. Is it possible to establish this for any values of a and b? If so, what would be the appropriate method of proof?

Edit: It seems like I made my question confusing, so let me clarify.

Can we guarantee at least one prime number that is form of a+nb, where n is either bigger prime than b, or only be factorized by bigger primes than b?
(a and b are coprime numbers)

Comment: You can't even  guarantee that $n$ will be odd.  Say $a=3$.  Then, if $b=p$ is a large (hence odd) prime then $a+nb$ prime requires that $n$ be even.

Comment: [some work](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression) has been done on the least prime in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but for here, I say even number for a. So 2,4,6 etc.

Comment: For no pair $(a,b)$ , it is known whether there are infinite many primes $n$ such that $an+b$ is prime. for $(a,b)=(2,1)$ this leads to the special open question whether there are infinite many Sophie-Germain primes. For $(a,b)=(1,2)$ it leads to the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: The Schinzel hypothesis implies that infinite many primes $n$ do the job whenever $a$ and $b$ are coprime.